# Pygame collision check bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

I recently started making Atari Breakout in Pygame and I encountered a weird bug. Whenever the ball touches the left side of the paddle, it bounces off normally but when it's on the right, it flies through the paddle. Please help, because I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
import pygame, random, math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Atari Breakout')

player = pygame.image.load('player copy.png')
ball = pygame.image.load('poland.png')

ballx, bally = 400, 300
balldx, balldy = 2,2
def isCollision(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))
    if distance <= 32:
        return True
    else:
        return False
running = True

while running:

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if isCollision(ballx, bally, pos[0], 525):
        balldy *= -1
    if bally >= 0:
        balldy *= -1
    if bally <= 570:
        balldy *= -1
    if ballx <= 0:
        balldx *= -1
    if ballx >= 770:
        balldx *= -1

    ballx += balldx
    bally += balldy

    screen.blit(player, (pos[0], 525))
    screen.blit(ball, (ballx,bally))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `isCollision` computes the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the top left of the rectangle which surrounds the ball and the top left of the paddle.
The shape of the player (paddle) is a rectangle with a very long and a very short side. Thus the collision algorithm doesn't work at all. I recommend to use `pygame.Rect` objects and `colliderect`, to detect a collision between the ball and the player. e.g.:

```py
def isCollision(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    ballRect = ball.get_rect(topleft = (x1, y1))
    playerRect = player.get_rect(topleft = (x2, y2))
    return ballRect.colliderect(playerRect)
```

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if isCollision(ballx, bally, pos[0], 525):
        balldy *= -1
```